# Compare two rows in one MySQL table, take result to sum rows in another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with client info:

```
Portfolios
accountId   Date        portfolio
Barney      2013-06-28  Slate
Barney      2013-07-01  Bedrock
Barney      2013-07-02  Bedrock
Fred        2013-06-28  Slate
Fred        2013-07-01  Slate
Fred        2013-07-02  Slate


Money
accountId   Date        value
Barney  2013-06-28  $100.00
Barney  2013-07-01  $101.00
Barney  2013-07-02  $103.00
Fred    2013-06-28  $500.00
Fred    2013-07-01  $503.00
Fred    2013-07-02  $498.00
```

I want to sum by date the portfolio values for each strategy - Slate and Bedrock. I can compare the two and get the running values for a particular strategy. For example:

```
SELECT Portfolios.accountId, Portfolios.Date, Portfolios.strategy,
     Money.accountId, Money.Date, Money.strategy, SUM(Money.value) as sumtotal
from Money, Portfolios
WHERE Money.accountId = Portfolios.accountId
AND Money.Date = Portfolios.Date
AND Portfolio.portfolio = 'Slate'
GROUP BY Date ORDER by Date ASC
```

This works.

```
Date        value
2013-06-28  $600.00
2013-07-01  $503.00
2013-07-02  $498.00
```

What I cannot get to work is comparing strategies across dates:

```
SUM (Money.value) WHERE Portfolios.strategy.date != Portfolios.strategy.date (-1)
GROUP BY Date
```

so that the query would ONLY return $100 (the last value of Barney's portfolio on 2013-06-28 before he switched strategies.

Comment: Clarification, please:  Can you give an example of the query result you'd like to see?  What happens if Barney's portfolio is in both slate and bedrock on July 1? (Or is that case prohibited by your business rules?)

Comment: He can't have both. So there is 1 portfolio strategy per accountId per Date
So the desired output would be
2013-06-28    $100

As in the original query, we would SUM(Money.value) as sumtotal, but only on Date where portfolio values have changed.
thanx!

Comment: `Portfolios.strategy.date != Portfolios.strategy.date` will never be different because its comparing against itself. you would need use a subquery or a join. Also is that `(-1)` a typo or you actually tried to deduce perhaps a day from the 2nd strategy.date or you wanted to compare it against the Money.strategy.date ?

Comment: you should be grouping by portfolio

Comment: This query works? You select two `dates`, and group by one of them, and somehow MySQL guesses which one!?! I think your version's better than mine!

Comment: Sorry for confusion
Portfolios.strategy.date != Portfolios.strategy.date (-1)
this is just to illustrate what I want to do - compare two row items in a table. I have not been able to determine how to do this.
e.g. 
Barney.2013-06-28.Slate  != Barney.2013-07-01.Bedrock

Comment: Is your `value` column a varchar with dollar signs in the strings?!

Comment: No 'value' is a decimal(20,2)

Comment: Slight update that might make things more clear:
     
     Portfolios
     accountId   Date        portfolio
     Barney      2013-06-28  Slate
     Barney      2013-06-28  Bedrock
     Barney      2013-07-01  Bedrock
     Barney      2013-07-02  Bedrock
     Fred        2013-06-28  Slate
     Fred        2013-07-01  Slate
     Fred        2013-07-02  Slate

I added a line so on 2013-06-28 Barney is in both Slate and Bedrock. This actually makes sense for accounting purposes. So the MySQL query I tried adding 'AND Portfolio.portfolio = 'Bedrock' but that didn't work.

Comment: i.e. trying to search where POrtfolios.portfolio = 'Slate' AND Portfolios.portfolio = 'Bedrock' did not work, as I guess once a single instance of the date is found, there cannot be others.